# Authenticate a smart phone (iOS, Android) by using wifi

Tags: android, ios, wifi, hardware, openwrt

I am working on a project in which I use a router (OpenWrt) to authenticate user (smartphone). Firstly, I intend to use phone number as a way to identify user but it turns out Apple and Google don't allow apps which use user's phone number (Smartphones access the Router via wifi  and send its phone number to be authenticated). Does anyone have better idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This will become more and more of an issue as the privacy movement(s) force vendors to remove any sort of long-term identification tokens (UDID, EIN, Phone Number, etc.)  My recommendation would be to have a one-time authentication process where the user logs on to the router one time and gets an magic cookie they can use for future automatic authentication.  Note that you'll have to be ware of man in the middle attacks and all the other issues related to stored authentication credentials.